# Integrate Autodesk-Forge service with Microsoft Dynamics 365 - Field Service Management App

Tags: c#, asp.net, autodesk-forge

We have a plan to integrate Autodesk-Forge service with Microsoft Dynamics 365 - Field Service Management App.
The integration scope is as follow :
         -Upload and view 2D/3D files (Revit, CAD, ..) into MS Dynamics 365 screen by using Forge viewer. 
         -Syncing model items list and Items properties to MS Dynamics 365.

Scope 01 - Upload and view model file:
We created an external ASP.Net Project (Version 4.6.1) then we used our 'FORGE_CLIENT_ID' and 'FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET' to upload and view a model.
We tried to publish our project to a local server and it was working fine but unfortunately once we published and deployed our project on Microsoft Azure, We are getting an unexpected error while trying to upload and view the model.

[Image On my localHost environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6j26.jpg)

[Image On Microsoft Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6uXQ.jpg)

Scope 02 - Syncing model items list and Items properties:
We know the APIs that need to be used in order to get the required data from Forge to Dynamics 365 but we have a lack knowledge of using 
Forge SDKs to use these APIs to get and insert returned results into Microsoft Dynamics 365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my comment to your 2 issues:

**Scope 01**: From the image of using MS Azure serve, it clearly mentioned that the 'FORGE_CLIENT_ID' and 'FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET' are missing on your Azure cloud server, did you set the 2 Ids as environment variables of the server? I believe that's the reason. And also please make sure the callback url you set on your Azure server is same as in your Forge App.

**Scope 2:** To get the model item list and also the properties, with .NET as server side language, you can use the .NET SDK with the following 3 APIs,

- [getmetadata](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/DerivativesApi.md#getmetadata)
- [getmodelviewmetadata](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/DerivativesApi.md#getmodelviewmetadata)
- [getmodelviewproperties](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/DerivativesApi.md#getmodelviewproperties)

I also find this code sample provided similar behavior as what you want with .NET API, please check at https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/model.derivative-csharp-context.menu/blob/master/TranslatorServer/Controllers/TranslatorController.cs#L173 , hope that answers your question and good luck with your Forget experience:)

Comment: Hi zhong,
Thanks a lot for your response. 

We reviewed the useful links that you mentioned before and it is working fine.

We can upload and view the model file as on step, now we need to review the uploaded file again so what is the correct way to do so?

Now we are trying to view an uploaded model file but while working on the ASP.Net application the model file was uploaded into the AppFolder into our solution not into the forge cloud service. (Is it mean that it doesn't uploaded to forge?)

Continue in below comment place.

Comment: Continue ....

First way, veiw the uploaded file from my AppFolder using bucket Key 'Nameof folder that creat when upload buket' and Object Name 'CAD or Revit file name with extention'. (But we got the exception is Error calling GetObject: {"reason":"Object not found"})

Second way, If the file uploaded to the forge service we can view by pathing bucket Key and Object Name.
ex:
my bucket Key  : forgeappd950174470004cd1be2d5b5a1044c8ce
my Object Name : architecturalannotationscalingandmultileaders.dwg

Continue in below comment place.

Comment: Continue ....

So, please advise what is the correct way to review an uploaded model file?

screenshot from error :

Comment: Are you asking how to view the uploaded model in web browser? if so, you just need to get the URN that returned from your translation job, and use that URN in Forge Veiwer, check https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewmodels for details. Btw, it's not clear to talking about the issue within comments, could you please mark this answer as solution and start a new post, so the question can be easily tracked and clearly answered:)

Comment: Well I'll do this, but
I know I have to use RUN, but my problem now is to access the file saved in the Applications folder
Thank you